# making PDF file to flipbook

Tags: linux, html, pdf

I need an open source html that convert PDF to Flipbook and I want to use it in linux server.
I've searched but found .exe document that doesn't work on linux server.
Thanks if you can help me to find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways of doing this but from your question it looks like you want to convert your documents on your server? FlexPaper supplies sample scripts in PHP and Java for how you can convert PDF documents to HTML5 and Flash in both GPL and commercial versions. You can give it a try here:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

Plain HTML can't convert pdf to flipbook.. Program called **ghostscript** can convert pdf to jpg/png in linux but the flipbook it self have to be maid/viewed usually with flash.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with this two programs runing over linux, I hope its usefull for you

[https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ghostscript/](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ghostscript) and
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/imagemagick/

Comment: Thanks a lot. But these links follow me to download ubuntu. I'm not so expert sorry to bother you. But how can I download the program or source or see the Demo?

Comment: you can use console to download the package with `sudo apt-get install ghostscript` if its debian, or follow this [link](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Install.htm)